# Help understanding an explanation about minimum description length principle

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection

I'm reading about MDL principle and my problem is on a book called: "Guide to intelligent data analysis", 2nd edition page 106.

I have added here a picture of the page I'm having trouble with. Could someone decode what the author is saying in the highlighted area:

[image]

It seems abstract and confusing...I get confused when he says that the original data is contained in the decompression rule itself?!...huh?... and because of that I don't understand the rest of it :/

Thank you for any help

Comment: With *decompression rule* the author means *decompression program* or *algorithm*. Otherwise this seems to be written perfectly clear.

Comment: not to me it isn't :) I need better details

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The perspective in the text you shared is very interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we had a data set. Something like this

```
1   M   17  B  
2   F   23  W
3   M   19  A
....
```

where the first variable is ID, second is sex, third is age and fourth is race ethnicity.

then, we create a code where `1` means

```
1   M   17  B  
2   F   23  W
3   M   19  A
....
```

and then we say "Our data set is 1, using our code".

This shifts all the complexity from the actual code number to the code algorithm. It's sort of silly, and the author is saying it is one extreme. The other extreme is to list the full data set.

In between.... well, that's the tricky part. We could say "The data has XXX men, XXX women, average age XXX, and is mostly White"; but there are a ton of other reasonable representations.